# Make background transparent without affecting contents

Tags: html, css

I have a complicated structure that goes like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="heading">
       <!-- more <div>'s -->
   </div>
   <div class="inner">
       <!-- more <div>'s -->
   </div>
   <div class="footer">
       <!-- more <div>'s -->
   </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to make the background of `.container` transparent at 90%. However, I need its *contents* (text, images, etc.) to remain **fully opaque**. I know it's a challenging task, but I tried the following:

```
.container {background: #fff; opacity: 0.9;}
.heading, .inner, .footer {opacity: 1.0;}
```

as well as the following:

```
.container, .heading, .inner, .footer {background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);}
```

The problem with #1 is that ALL descendants of `.container` become transparent and resetting their opacity just does not work. In my #2 attempt, I set transparency of every div using `rgba`, but the problem is that *child divs are being set transparent in relation to their parents*; as a result, I do not get a "uniform" transparency across all divs.

Since neither `opacity` nor `rgba` seem to be reasonable, I feel the following might work:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="transparent"></div>
   <div class="heading">
      <!-- more <div>'s -->
   </div>
   ...
```

Then, play with `position` and `height` of `.transparent` so that every other div in `container` goes on top of it.

Can anyone please help me figure this out or possibly suggest a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you had first tried works for me:

```css
body {background: green; }
.container {background: #fff; opacity: 0.9;}
.heading, .inner, .footer {opacity: 1.0; background:#000; border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
       <div class="heading">
           <!-- more <div>'s -->
       </div>
       <div class="inner">
           <!-- more <div>'s -->
       </div>
       <div class="footer">
           <!-- more <div>'s -->
       </div>
    </div>
```

I added some color so it would be more apparent what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

remove the opacity stuff and run only this:

```
.container {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setting `background-color` to `.container` should work without influencing it's descendants' backgrounds. By default, `background-color` is `transparent`, so if you don't have anything set specifically for the descendants, then they'll be transparent thus appearing to inherit `background-color`. I have set the `background-colors` individually to each element and a few of them have not  applied a `background-color`, it should be obvious which ones they are.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.container {
  outline: 5px dotted red;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.heading,
.inner,
.footer {
  outline: 3px dashed blue;
  width: 50%;
}
.heading {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}
.footer {
  margin-left: 50%;
  background: lime;
}
.heading div,
.inner div,
.footer div {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
}
div > div > div:nth-child(4n-1) + div {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
div > div > div:nth-child(2n+1) {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
div > div > div:nth-child(3n-5) {
  margin-left: 75%;
}
div > div > div:nth-child(3n-2) {
  background: red;
}
div > div > div:nth-child(3n-1) +div {
  background: black; color: white;
}
div > div > div:nth-child(2n-6) {
  background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div>3</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```